# Is it possible to copy the remotes of origin to the local clone

Tags: git

Lets say I have a repository on a server somewhere (call it "*origin*") which has remotes pointing somewhere else (lets call that server "*parent*").

When cloning *origin* to my local PC, is there a way to automatically create a remote on my local machine pointing to *parent* (in addition to the remote pointing to *origin*)?

Comment: IME that's not possible.

Comment: @Sathya: is is possible under certain condition. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remotes are declared in the *local* config file of a git repo.
And config file is **[never shared amongst cloned repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547933/is-it-possible-to-clone-git-config-from-remote-location/6548056#6548056)**.

So unless you have:

- those remote names and addresses in a file with a recognizable content
- a [.gitattributes filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728) able to trigger a smudge scruipt on checkout:

(The "recognizable" requirement is there because a [filter script has only the content of a file in input, not its name or path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059326/git-equivalent-of-subversions-url-keyword-expansion/2059393#2059393))

[image: smudge]

That smudge script will then be able to:

- read the remote name and addresses you want to declare
- check if a remote name isn't already there
- if not, will add that remote.

My point is: you need to extract that *config* information (the remotes, which, like all configs, are never shared) into a file, managed in the Git repo.